# heroku paperclip rails 4 s3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am having trouble getting heroku to work with s3. When i submit an image post, it seems my application submits it(what i can tell from heroku logs). But no image shows up after submission except for a blank post. And there is no image in the s3 bucket. I followed documentation from: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3 for s3 and here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip for paperlip.

```
    production.rb 

    config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    # s3_host_name: 's3.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }



$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
$ heroku config:set AWS_REGION=us-east-1


Heroku Logs

2016-12-28T21:57:52.101029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-12-28T21:57:52.101275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-12-28T21:57:57.778592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 30838 -e production`
2016-12-28T21:58:02.108725+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-12-28 21:58:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-12-28T21:58:02.108742+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-12-28 21:58:02] INFO  ruby 2.2.6 (2016-11-15) [x86_64-linux]
2016-12-28T21:58:02.109000+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-12-28 21:58:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=30838
2016-12-28T21:58:02.570577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-12-28T21:58:04.144516+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-12-28T21:58:04.144539+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:30838
2016-12-28T21:58:04.144541+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-12-28T21:58:04.144541+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-12-28T21:58:04.144542+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/posts" for 162.199.225.97 at 2016-12-28 21:58:04 +0000
2016-12-28T21:58:04.185386+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
2016-12-28T21:58:04.185468+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L8jVCl6TKg9movpIhk8pt6P9oAv2h7c8sNGHu3n3XhoAke5HgoQuRMncUje71ng/EzSsrBxP5bUBrByTqWALEw==", "post"=>{"content"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8aaa6441a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161228-4-mfx8dx.jpg>, @original_filename="best-kitten-names-1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"best-kitten-names-1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Post"}
2016-12-28T21:58:04.205630+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.264197+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.7ms)  BEGIN
2016-12-28T21:58:04.268176+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["content", ""], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-12-28 21:58:04.264795"], ["updated_at", "2016-12-28 21:58:04.264795"]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.270377+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.6ms)  COMMIT
2016-12-28T21:58:04.271066+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://immense-gorge-61510.herokuapp.com/users/1
2016-12-28T21:58:04.271231+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 86ms (ActiveRecord: 12.4ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.271721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/posts" host=immense-gorge-61510.herokuapp.com request_id=e3e74cff-240a-4041-bc5b-5e4bae727b53 fwd="162.199.225.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=135ms status=302 bytes=1168
2016-12-28T21:58:04.562237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/1" host=immense-gorge-61510.herokuapp.com request_id=b17a22b5-d8f7-4305-860d-7366fbd8e8f1 fwd="162.199.225.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=143ms status=200 bytes=5100
2016-12-28T21:58:04.425366+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/1" for 162.199.225.97 at 2016-12-28 21:58:04 +0000
2016-12-28T21:58:04.428258+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
2016-12-28T21:58:04.428277+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-12-28T21:58:04.430570+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.434624+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.438495+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.459392+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (user_id = 1)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.470197+00:00 app[web.1]:   Post Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (user_id = 1)  ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
2016-12-28T21:58:04.473733+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.489307+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.490576+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.492301+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.493573+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.494749+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.496086+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.497785+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.498880+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_wall.html.slim (34.4ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.513974+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.slim (6.4ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.515710+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_post_form.html.slim (16.2ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.515770+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/show.html.slim within layouts/application (73.9ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.552423+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."checked" = $2  [["recipient_id", 1], ["checked", "f"]]
2016-12-28T21:58:04.553223+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.slim (26.5ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.560863+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.slim (6.3ms)
2016-12-28T21:58:04.561408+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 133ms (Views: 116.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)
```

Comment: are you using the fog gem?

Comment: I am not. Should I?

Comment: Yes. Try it and also ImageMagic for reducing file size. I don't see anything in the heroku logs that raise a red flag. Fog is an easy way to get photos to S3, and if it fails you'll get an error message.

Comment: i tried following this, but didn't have any success. http://jessicag.github.io/Using-Paperclip-AWS-and-Fog/

Comment: So exactly what happens when you select a photo to upload and you click the "submit" button? Maybe look at your logs.

Comment: Curious about how heroku is involved at this point. You s/b in the development mode to sort this out, then deploy.

Comment: You'll also have to migrate your database, both locally and after you deploy to heroku, the production database  (in the command line:  heroku run rake db:migrate  )

Comment: After i hit the submit button an empty post loads. The image, i'm not sure what happens to it, but it is not saved in any way. It's not in the s3 bucket or posted. However the logs show the image being submitted. This is now happening in both development and production.

Comment: https://immense-gorge-61510.herokuapp.com is the location of the app. If you want to take a look at whats going on for yourself.

Comment: Post the pertinent part of the development log (and you did the migrations, right? and restarted the server?)

Comment: heroku reports app still in development... rather see your Rails code

Comment: This is a comprehensive tutorial on the subject, and I highly recommend it:  https://rails.devcamp.com/trails/rails-project-photo-uploader-tutorial

Comment: PostsController#create as HTML
2016-12-29T03:09:58.864346+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yu7xLpKdXfgH3FrMXwVMIFQjUrSoNfXtnJ2e+QTXYORAtu7lVfZd0/m9Eea1gJzsvL+Rl3DifmIRsktI9EBTmA==", "post"=>{"content"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbd8cca7d20 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161229-4-4r86ub.jpg>, @original_filename="best-kitten-names-1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"best-kitten-names-1.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Post"}

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like the picture went into your tempfile instead of to S3. Now you know you have to configure the bucket. Pay close attention to this page:
https://rails.devcamp.com/rails-project-photo-uploader-tutorial/connecting-to-s3-on-aws/how-to-connect-to-the-aws-s3-api
You're close! Don't give up.